# Inequality $(1+a_2)^{2}(1+a_3)^{3}... (1+a_n)^{n}>n^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

I need help proving this inequality.

Let $a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ be positive non zero real numbers such that their product is $1$

Prove that

$$(1+a_2)^{2}(1+a_3)^{3}... (1+a_n)^{n}>n^{n}$$

I tried Bernoulli that yields a LHS greater than $n! $

I also tried a trig $tan^{2}$ substitution without success...

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your title and description look different.

Comment: This is IMO 2012/2. You can easily look it up on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the headsup Calvin

A great solution here:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/2012_IMO_Problems/Problem_2